# R.java is not created

Tags: java, android, android-studio, r.java-file

I've found out that my R.java is never created. I'm using Android Studio and rebuilding does not solve the problem as well.

As far as i can see i don't have any mistakes in my XMLfiles as well.
I'm using W7. The error cannot resolve symbol R resolves.

Please help!

[Code can be found here](http://www.android-hilfe.de/android-app-entwicklung/472306-r-layout-activity.html)

Comment: Let the stackoverflow folks decide if there are mistakes in your XMLs - paste them here.

Comment: you have to find errors in your XMLs. OR Clean your Project.

Comment: clean and build the project again , and set the option to automatic build

Comment: added a link to the code

Comment: What's your Android Studio version?

Comment: Could you add: com.example.sampleapp.R to your imports?

Comment: the newest - and i cant add com.example.sampleapp.R - android studio want to import android.R but i know that it's wrong

also my sdk is updated, and i already tried to reinstall android studio - it did not fix the problem.

It shouldnt be a big deal - as you can see its an extreme simple project...

Comment: definately a duplicate question.  Look at the imports in your source for "Import Android.R"  and delete it.  This happened to me in the eclipse ADT.  I tried to use the beta android studio tool but it feels like a path to a "pay for tool" so I stopped using it.

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle`? Also, check the build folder inside the AS project folder. Check the `classes` folder and see if there's something there.

Comment: theres no import andorid.R - and yes that question is several times in the internet but nowhere i found an answer -

gradle added to the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new project and copy-pasted your code and it works fine (in Intellij IDEA 12 at least). I have dropped the line (this one `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`) with theme because you haven't provided code for your theme.

If you haven't added any gfx or other files and you're absolutely sure about the correctness of you theme style, then try to create a new project and do the same I did - code copy & paste.

Comment: already copy pasted it once - deleted the style theme... did not fix my project 
minimum api 7 / 2.2(froyo)
target sdk 16 (jelly bean)
compile with api 17 (jelly bean)

Comment: What is the IDE that you're using?

Comment: using the IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: That is really weird because I use Intellij IDEA as well and as I said everything is fine. Have you tried to remove theme?

Comment: And is everything OK when you create an empty project and run it?

Comment: created an empty project - does not run... how can i fix my android studio? re install?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Because now it is obvious that the problem is not in project but in IDE/IDE configuration itself.

Comment: i gonna try that and than tell you if it worked - thank ya all

Answer (score 1):

If you have an error on your any code. No **clean/build** works to build **R.java**.

Just check your whole codes fix errors **manually** *(Because of R.java is not builded it will show errors everywhere. So you have to find and fix errors on your own.)*

Comment: check my code - click at the link - its a really small and i cant find any error.

Commenting the R. error out and rebuild it after it does not help as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually due to an unaccepted character in the resources names, check for dashes, spaces and caps and let the project refresh

Comment: the xml files have the names main, acitivityanother and strings - no spaces dashes or caps used - i googled before i asked this :>

Comment: I'm talking about images, sounds...etc It's just ONE possible reason